TypeScript type error with multiple accounts in program struct
I'm going through the Full Stack Solana tutorial.
Here's the initialize struct:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
 
    // Create and initialize `Counter` account using a PDA as the address
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"counter"], // optional seeds for pda
        bump,                 // bump seed for pda
        payer = user,
        space = 8 + Counter::INIT_SPACE
    )]
    pub counter: Account<'info, Counter>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

which compiles into the following IDL type in the account object:
      "accounts": [
        {
          "name": "user",
          "writable": true,
          "signer": true
        },
        {
          "name": "counter",
          "writable": true,
          "pda": {
            "seeds": [
              {
                "kind": "const",
                "value": [
                  99,
                  111,
                  117,
                  110,
                  116,
                  101,
                  114
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "system_program",
          "address": "11111111111111111111111111111111"
        }
      ],

This generates a union type of all three fields. However, when passing the PDA into the Initialize function:
  const [counterPDA] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("counter")],
    program.programId
  );

  const txSig = program.methods
    .initialize()
    .accounts({
      counter: counterPDA,
    })
    .rpc();

I get the following type error:
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'counter' does not exist in type 'ResolvedAccounts<{ name: "user"; writable: true; signer: true; } | { name: "counter"; writable: true; pda: { seeds: [{ kind: "const"; value: [99, 111, 117, 110, 116, 101, 114]; }]; }; } | { name: "systemProgram"; address: "11111111111111111111111111111111"; }>'.ts(2353)


Surprisingly, when I remove the "name": "user", field from the "accounts" object, there is no type error, even though as shown above, program.methods.initialize().accounts takes in a union type. How do I resolve this type issue?

TL;DR, use accountsStrict instead of accounts if you want to explicitly specify all the accounts
You are probably using the latest version of anchor which made changes to the IDL, https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/pull/2824 and introduces three new ways to specify the accounts,

accounts - specify only the required accounts.

accountsStrict - specify all the accounts that an instruction takes.

accountsPartial - let anchor resolve some accounts for you.


docs: https://www.anchor-lang.com/release-notes/0.30.0#account-resolution

Thank you, using accountsPartial worked!
